# Add class but change specific width for a single item

Tags: jquery, css

I'm adding a class to a text field using jQuery with the following code:

```
$('[name="albdesign_wc_donation_from_single_page"]').addClass( "input-text" );
```

The width of that class is 100% but just for this specific object I'd like to specify the width but keep the remaining CSS. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an extra class to handle that or set the CSS using `.width()` or `.css()`:

```
$('[name="albdesign_wc_donation_from_single_page"]').addClass( "input-text" ).css('width', '100px');

$('[name="albdesign_wc_donation_from_single_page"]').addClass( "input-text" ).width(100);
```